# How to fix OLE error while parsing emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook, win32com

I am facing an OLE error while my outlook is being parsed through python using win32com module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for i, message in enumerate(messages):
pywintypes.com_error: (-520879857, 'OLE error 0xe0f4010f', None, None)
```

I believe this is due to a network connection which might be restarting after a particular amount of time.

```
inbox= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders["Inbox"]
messages = inbox.Items
for i, message in enumerate(messages):
```

Comment: Traceback 
    for i, message in enumerate(messages):
  File "C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64\envs\testconda\lib\site-packages\win3
nt\dynamic.py", line 252, in __getitem__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._enum_.__getitem__(index))
  File "C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64\envs\testconda\lib\site-packages\win3
nt\util.py", line 37, in __getitem__
    return self.__GetIndex(index)
  File "C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64\envs\testconda\lib\site-packages\win3
nt\util.py", line 53, in __GetIndex
    result = self._oleobj_.Next(1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-520879857, 'OLE error 0xe0f4010f', None, None)

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
 for i, message in enumerate(messages):
```

Instead, I'd suggest getting a subset of items and process them in a batch. For example, you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods to get a subset of items (according to your conditions) and process them. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

[How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

[How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Comment: Can you please help me with the list of filters like [UnRead] =true? I need filters for subject contains, has attachment, attachment name contains, sender is etc. for the emails.